# How to reliably get the URL from which the sendBeacon was made from?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to send to the backend the URL from which the `sendBeacon` was sent from, so I currently do it like so:

```
const url = "/some/url",
    data = new FormData(),
    pathname = window.location.pathname;

data.append("pathname", pathname);
navigator.sendBeacon(url, data);
```

But that can be modified by the users.

Is there a reliable way to send the current `pathname` via `sendBeacon` to the backend?

Using `HTTP_REFERER` in the backend is not a valid option either, so I need to use something else

Comment: A built-in mechanism to automatically send the actual value does not exist AFAIK, and anything you implement yourself, could be manipulated.

Comment: Yep. I am not sure if there's a reliable way then to do it. I just thought that, since `sendBeacon` is exclusive to browsers and can't be made from API platforms like postman, then maybe they made a built-in referer in the beacon request. Would've been nice

Comment: _"since sendBeacon is exclusive to browsers and can't be made from API platforms like postman"_ - just because it was implemented in browsers under a specific function name, does not mean you could not send the exact same HTTP request it will cause, using postman or any other HTTP clients ...

Comment: Yes you are correct I just thought that, when you send via HTTP clients like postman, I can at least check against the user agent for the browser (so if it's not I just return error), but that's is really wrong. lol I was completely wrong on that one. Definitely, you can ignore that statement haha

Comment: What underlying problem are you actually trying to solve by attempting to send the URL from which the request came? Perhaps there is a better way, or an established technique for that scenario.

Comment: I want to know on which page the user is on currently (live, using websockets). It works as it is now with `pathname`, but just thought about the fact that it can be altered by users

Comment: `I want to know on which page the user is on currently`...yes, but _why_, was my question. Is it a security issue (e.g. affecting some permissions or access), or is it just about getting some other functionality to work properly? If it's the former, the users being able to modify it is a big problem we need to address. If it's the latter, then it doesn't matter so much and arguably it's the user's own stupid fault if they muck about with the code/data and cause a fault which means their page malfunctions. This is true of almost any website really.

Comment: It's not a security issue, but still, I wish I could get the right information about the user (because it's sort of a game) so if a user lies about his location on the website it breaks the goal of it, even though it's not a security issue

Comment: Would lying about the location constitute a breach of the game's rules? If so then arguably that is a security issue of sorts, or at least a validation issue. Ultimately though, that is always going to be a flaw in a HTTP web application. You can't force a user to identify their real location (either geographical or in terms of an online site or server where the request originated). _Anything_ sent from the client side is open to abuse, in theory. Is there any disincentive for the user to lie in this case? e.g. would it spoil the game for them too (not just for other players)?

Comment: It could break some stuff but then of course I'm going to do another check. What I was thinking is to set a session with some token, like CSRF token, and save it in the frontend as a cookie or in the LocalStorage. Then, it will be appended to every request back to the server. If there's a mismatch I will throw an error. So in the backend it would be like something like URL as the key of the session and the token as the value. That should be sufficient right?

Comment: Sufficient for what? That would certainly tell you that each request is coming from the same browser session (barring the possibility of session hijacking vulnerabilities, but hopefully you mitigate those risks). It still doesn't tell you where the request came from. But it wasn't clear if it was the location which was actually important, or if that was just a proxy for trying to understand who the user is? Do users have to log into your application? Setting that up is by far the simplest way of trying to identify users and sessions.

Comment: Oh yes, the location is the important thing. Note that I meant that I will do the session key-value for the URL, not the user (The user is already authenticated and has his own session). So in the backend it should tell me not only where it came from, but also if the page wasn't altered in the frontend request. Let's say when a user opens the page `example.com/page-x`, then I will create a session in the backend `page-x: some-encrypted-token`, and send it to the frontend. In the frontend I will send the `pathname` as I already do, but with the added token. Then, I will compare both for a match

Comment: Session cookies are already per-domain, by default (and can't be read by JS code from other domains, to help prevent hijacking). Do you need it specifically by page, for some reason?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed a few typos I had in the comment. Yes I need specifically to get the page. So I already send the page via the `sendBeacon` and `window.location.pathname`. But was afraid it would be altered by the user. Now if I add another session in the backend - I will send the token encrypted to the frontend (per page). So I will send the encrypted token back to the backend on every request with the `sendBeacon`, and compare against the backend session key with the specific page

Comment: For example, the GET request to `example.com/page-x` will set a backend session with the token value for that page. I will then send the encrypted value to the frontend for that page. And on every `sendBeacon` I will send both `window.location.pathname` and the token, and verify against the backend session. But now that I think of it.. it doesn't matter, the user can simply call that endpoint and append the token himself going to that page first 

Comment: Yes it's not foolproof. Say you have page-x and page-y, the user could visit both, get tokens for both, and then manually adjust them when sending requests (so they could get the page-y token, then go to page-x, and when the beacon is sent, they could intercept and adjust both the token and the pathname. But it's certainly harder than it was before. And it's still unclear to me what benefit that would give to a user.

Comment: You are right, there is no benefit to the user, as he now can't actually perform the tasks needed in that page except for faking the location. So you are right, there is no benefit and it is no longer a security issue. It might be enough then! (One of the goals was to track the user in the website real-time, so if he just fakes his location, OK, there's nothing else that can be done now). Also, thank you for the tips